# Как сделать кастомная функцию sprintf?

Tags: php, sprintf

Как мне сделать кастомную функцию по типу sprintf, с неограниченными задаваемыми параметрами?
Написал такой код:

```
function customSprintf($format, ...$params)
{
    return sprintf($format, $params);
}
```

Выводит ворнинг: **"Warning: Too few arguments in ..."** и возвращает **NULL**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы передать массив как неограниченный список аргументов нужно тоже использовать троеточие:

```
function customSprintf($format, ...$params)
{
    return sprintf($format, ...$params);
}
```

Количество передаваемых аргументов в функцию sprintf должно быть не менее, чем количество аргументов в форматируемой строке, иначе вы так и будете получать предупреждение.

Можно также вручную подсчитать количество аргументов в форматируемой строке и заполнить недостающие аргументы пустыми строками, получив на выходе более лояльную версию sprintf:

```
function customSprintf($format, ...$params)
{
    if (preg_match_all("~%(?:(\d+)[$])?[-+]?(?:[ 0]|['].)?(?:[-]?\d+)?(?:[.]\d+)?[%bcdeEufFgGosxX]~", $format, $expected) > 0)
    {
        $expected = intval(max($expected[1], count(array_unique($expected[1]))));

        if (count($params) < $expected)
        {
            $n = $expected - count($params);
            $params = array_merge($params, array_fill(0, $n, ''));
        }
    }

    return sprintf($format, ...$params);
}
```